# remove google account from android device

Tags: google-account

if i sync a google account account to my android mobile, all my gmail, contacts will be synced with the google account and i can view my mobile contacts, photos from a web browser in pc by signing in my google account right. now my question is simple. if i remove my google account from my android mobile, will i still be able to view the already synced contacts and photos from a web browser in pc through internet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. 
If you have synced the account properly then you will be able to access all your content from browser even though you remove the account from android device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will still be able to view any of that synced data that you can view from a different device.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of this process is not technically correct. For a full explanation of how this process works read: [How Google Sync Works](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/38584/how-does-google-contacts-sync-works) and [Google Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sync).

I will give my understanding of the matter and hope it

Lets say you have Contact_A on your Phone. When you configure a G-Mail account on your phone to sync your contacts Google grab Contact_A from your local device (phone) and then syncs with your *Google* account. Once this is done, this contact is then associated with your google account and is added to their database. This is controlled by Google and when you login to their service you're accessing your account through their product.

By syncing (and completing) this on your phone, Google will then store a copy of all the contacts on their server and will allow you to access this via a browser. You can successfully unlink your phone.

Obviously this method does not allow you to keep your phone and cloud sync unless you re-add. The best option here for you (I assume) would be to simply disable the "sync contacts" field on your phone.

If you believe anything here is wrong please feel free to correct me - I'm here to learn too.
If a sufficient answer please mark it so.